# How I get my sharepoint 4 visual webpart in a single usercontrol to add in page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 4 visual webparts working properly. 
I want to get it into one usercontrol(.ascx) file so I can use all of it as a single tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for multiple user controls.

```
public class MyVisualWebPart : WebPart
{
    private const string strUserControlPath = @"~/CONTROLTEMPLATES/MyVisualWebPart.ascx";

    public MyVisualWebPart()
    {
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = this.Page.LoadControl(strUserControlPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want it..My requirement is to I have master page and i want to use one user control put in it so all webparts that are in my user control(.ascx) file display on page. SO,, How can i get my visual webparts in user control and display as one control just put in master page.......